# How should I handle repeated updating in logical programming?

Tags: prolog, scheme, minikanren

In particular I am trying to determine the best approach to solve the following type of problem:

The example I am interested in is the find-s algorithm in Mitchell's Machine Learning book were it is applied to 4 training examples.

The basic idea is for each training example, x, and hypothesis h, determine h' were it incorporates x by making it more general. I need to map h to h' for each x in the training set. The problem I am having is how to best approach this in a logical programming language. I am using minikanren which is roughly prolog embedded in scheme.

After computing each h', I need to then set! it to a global variable h, and then proceed to the next training example x. The code below is the main part of the program.

```
(define h '(0 0 0 0 0 0))

(define seto
  (lambda (x)
    (project (x)
             (lambda (s) (set! h x) (succeed s)))))

(run* (q)
     (fresh (x h0 h1)
            (trainingo x)
            (== h h0)
            (find-so h0 x h1)
            (seto h1)
            (== h1 q)))
```

h is the global variable, seto mutates h with h1 which is the next computed hypothesis from h0 and x training example using the find-s algorithm (find-so).

In prolog it would be (I think) equivalent to **assert('hypothesis'(H))** after each training example X (overwriting the the previous one) and calling **retract('hypothesis'(H))** after all the training examples have been applied.

Again my question is whether this is the best approach (via side-effects) for solving these kind of  problems?

Edit:
I accepted @mat answer in conjunction with his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167816/how-should-i-handle-repeated-updating-in-logical-programming#comment67625293_40170550). In summary I needed to treat the training examples as a list and use forward recursion on that list until I got to the empty list. Were I was getting stuck was in having the training examples as part of the backtracking along with finding the next hypothesis instead of having them in a list of which I can recur on until empty.

Comment: You need to explain why exactly you want to do this via side effects. The answer by @mat explains why you shouldn't need side effects for this.

Comment: By the way, you can find examples in Prolog library code of using side effects for efficiency reasons. See [this code in SWI-Prolog's library(aggregate)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate_all/3). In any case, you would end up using predicates from the `nb_*` family, where "nb" stands for "non-backtrackable".

Comment: I mentioned this as a comment in @mat answer: "...problem I am having is after I get the next hypothesis and then backtrack to the next training example -- I have lost my next hypothesis. I don't want to use side-effects to resolve this if possible."

Comment: don't backtrack. chain the hypothesis updating: h1 + x1 = h2; h2 + x2 = h3; ...; hn + xn = final_h . (see also [@mat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167816/how-should-i-handle-repeated-updating-in-logical-programming#comment67625293_40170550)).

Comment: To add to the other comments: you can change Prolog's default depth-first search strategy (through the proof tree) and you should, if this is what your problem requires. In "The Craft of Prolog" there is a whole chapter on different search strategies and how to implement them.

Comment: @Boris Thanks, but I did not need that approach. Minikanren has conde for depth-first and condi for breadth-first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you suggest may seem *tempting*: Simulate global updates with `assertz/0` and `retract/1`.

However, there are **major drawbacks** if you do it this way:

- Using global states prevents you from *using* and *testing* your predicates **in isolation**.
- Using destructive updates prevents you from using your predicates **in more directions**.
- The subtle and implicit dependencies of global states make changes in your predicates very **error prone**.

---

A **declarative** solution to simulate these state changes is to think in terms of **relations between states**.

For example, when you use `H0` to compute the *next* hypothesis `H1`, then you can express this as a relation between `H0` and `H1`, and possibly further parameters. Think about predicates like:

- `hypothesis_next(H0, H1)`
- `algorithm_hypothesis_next(A, H0, H1)`
- `parameters_hypothesis_next(Ps, H0, H1)`
- etc.

Note that such predicates can be *read* and—ideally—*run* in all directions!

In total, the entire solution will in your case be modeled as a **sequence of hypotheses**:

> `H0` → `H1` → `H2` → … → **`H`**

For more information and pointers, see the closely related question:

[**How to avoid using assert and retractall in Prolog to implement global (or state) variables**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005042/how-to-avoid-using-assert-and-retractall-in-prolog-to-implement-global-or-state)

Comment: thanks! But the problem I am having is after I get the next hypothesis and then **backtrack** to the next training example -- I have lost my next hypothesis. I don't want to use side-effects to resolve this if possible.

Comment: A solution for this is to replace backtracking by **forward recursion**. Say you have training examples `Es` to refine your hypothesis `H0`. You can describe this with a predicate like: `examples_h0_h([], H, H).` (saying: if there are no examples, then the final hypothesis is the same as the initial one) and `examples_h0_h([E|Es], H0, H) :- hypothesis_next(E, H0, H1), examples_h0_h(Es, H1, H).`, gradually refining the hypothesis with each example. Since this pattern occurs rather frequently in Prolog, there is a meta-predicate called `foldl/4` for this: `foldl(hypothesis_next, Es, H0, H)`